# Electron add/remove files in system folders as single operation

Tags: node.js, command-line, permissions, electron

I have an Electron app which installs files from a temporary `App Data` folder, into System directories. To be able to write to a System directory the Electron process needs to run with Admin privileges.

It is considered bad practice to run the entire Electron app as Admin. VSCode and other popular Electron apps usually show a dialog, and then run only that single sub-process command with Admin privileges.

[image]

My challenge is that I have multiple files/folders to add/remove, showing a dialog for every single operation is not a good user experience.

Source: `/Users/username/Library/Preferences/my-electron-app`:

```
/downloads
  /filea.txt
  /fileb.txt
  /systemfilea.bin
  /systemfileb.bin
```

Destination: `/Users/username/Library/Example`:

```
/Docs
  /filea.txt
  /fileb.txt
/System
  /systemfilea.bin
  /systemfileb.bin
```

Therefore I need a way to batch all operations into a single command. These would need to work cross-platform (Linux, Mac, Windows). Some options i've considered:

**Node script**

Run a node script passing arguments for each file, or some kind or filter.

```
node custom.js --file filea.txt --file fileb.txt --output /Users/username/Library/Example && node custom.js --file systemfilea.bin --file systemfileb.bin --output /Users/username/Library/Example/System
```

**System commands**

Run system commands such as `cp`, `mv`, `rm`. But would need to take multiple arguments to add/remove multiple files/folders. In addition would need to only remove empty directories.

```
cp -R /Users/username/Library/Preferences/my-electron-app/downloads/*.txt /Users/username/Library/Example/Docs
cp -R /Users/username/Library/Preferences/my-electron-app/downloads/*.bin /Users/username/Library/Example/System
```

**Custom binary**

Build a custom binary which performs the exact operations I need

```
custom-app install --docs --system
```

Another way? Which approach is recommended and prevents me having to maintain lots of custom code?

Comment: Have you taken a look at libraries that make system commands like rm cross-environment compatible like rimraf? 

Also afaik, the system wouldn't ask the user to grant admin perms multiple times if a single task requires admin perms regardless of the number of items that you're operating on in one task.

Comment: `rimraf` would allow be to use glob searches on files and bulk remove them. But I would still need to run as a node script. I think running a node script is probably the right approach, but will need to find a good way to separate the functionality into its own process. Using a glob would simplify the inputs though!

Comment: That is a given I'd say. I think you'll have to spawn a child process, ask for elevated perms, do your job then terminate that child process. When/If you figure it out, post an answer here, I'm sure someone else will be able to use it.